# MongoDB eval() with arguments

Tags: mongodb, eval

I'm getting a strange result when trying to use `eval` with the `args` argument.  The following works fine:

```
> db.eval(function(coll) {
  var res = db[coll].find({});
  return(res.count());
}, ['KenColl'])
1438
```

But when I pass a second argument, I always get empty results, even if I don't use it:

```
> db.eval(function(coll, query) {
  var res = db[coll].find({});
  return(res.count());
}, ['KenColl', {}])
0
```

Am I misunderstanding something about `eval` and `args`?  I'm running version 2.4.3 of both `mongod` and the `MongoDB` shell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For [db.eval](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.eval/#db.eval) you shouldn't pass the arguments as an array, just pass them into the function.

The following example should work:

```
db.eval(function(coll, query) {
  var res = db[coll].find(query);
  return(res.count());
}, 'KenColl', {})
```

*p.s. your first example only works because in javascript `db['KenColl'] === db[['KenColl']]`*

Comment: Did this change in recent versions of the DB?  I'm looking at the "Definitive Guide" book by Chodorow and Dirolf, and on page 105 it shows `db.eval` taking an array as the second argument.  Or is that just an error in the text?

Comment: if you pass it an array and the function expects a single argument then the argument will be an array with however many arguments you put in it.

Comment: @AsyaKamsky: in the book though, it shows `db.eval("function(x,y,z){ return x+y+z; }", [num1, num2, num3])`, which I just confirmed in my shell doesn't work as expected.

Comment: yeah, I just checked - that syntax doesn't work with spidermonkey shell with 2.0 nor with V8 shell in 2.4.  That book was written circa v1.4(?) unless you have a new printing...

Comment: I just confirmed, this example is NOT in the new printing of the book so you are looking at the older one.  New one: http://www.amazon.com/MongoDB-Definitive-Guide-Kristina-Chodorow/dp/1449344682/